# What files in an IPA file are signed?

Tags: ios, digital-signature, ios-provisioning

I've been getting into iOS development and starting researching the structure of IPA files.

After unzipping a few applications I noticed there are `_CodeSignature` folders in the main app folder but also in framework and extension subfolders.

Also I saw there are 3 groups of binaries in the file:

1. Main Application Binary
2. Framework Binaries
3. Extension Binaries

(Please correct me if I left out any)

So my question is **what files actually need signing in an IPA file?**

**Do I sign folder structure too?**

There isn't a lot of documentation on this subject (mostly references to automated tools that sign applications) but I wanted to get a better technical understanding about it.

Any help would be appreciated.